# Log off user after 12 hours of inactivity using zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, session-variables

Hi Guys I have been working on this for more than 2 days now. I have two types of users (admin and guest) and would like only admin to be logged out after 12 hours of inactivity. Below is what I have done but it logs out after a few minutes.

Zend_Session::rememberMe(43200);

I have seen online resources stating that I will have to set these session variables in my config.ini file. 
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime =`43200
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 43200
resources.session.cookie_lifetime = 43200

The issues with the above approach is that is sets the variables globally and give the guests access to remains logged in for 12 hours.

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to store
    Zend_Session::rememberMe(43200); in session variable in config.ini
you can call that when you are checking for authentication for example in auth controller's authentication action or something similar.
and based on the condition you can check if your user is admin, then you can execute
Zend_Session::rememberMe(43200);
else not.

hope this helps..

Comment: I have already done that in processadmin action in my controller. And the seesion doesn't last for 12 hours as expected